# How to convert async AsyncIterable<Uint8Array> to File in Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, file, blob, uint8array

Hello I'm sending/POST a File from a HTML Form on a browser client to a Remix application server.

The Remix applicaton server is sending/handling my File as a async AsyncIterable.
I now need to convert it back to a File object so I can send it to a backend server as FormData.

I tried both with and without buffer for demo:

Does anyone have experiance with convert AsyncIterable to Blob then to File??

```
const myHandler: UploadHandler = async ({ name, contentType, data, filename }) => {
  //'data' is data of type AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>
  //'contentType' is 'image/png'

  let dataArray1 = []; //test1 without buffer
  let dataArray2 = []; //test2 with buffer

  for await (const x of data) {
    dataArray1.push(x); //without buffer
    dataArray2.push(x.buffer); //with buffer
  }

  const blob1 = new Blob(dataArray1, {type: contentType});
  const blob2 = new Blob(dataArray2, {type: contentType});

  const file1 = new File([blob1], filename, { type: contentType });
  const file2 = new File([blob2], filename, { type: contentType });
  console.log('file1.size: ', file1.size); 
  //file1 size is 1336843 (and for file2)
  //but i'm getting content-length 1337028 from my browser Form
  //so I'm not sure if it's correct

  return file1;
};
```

[![content-length size][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

[image]

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: When i'm sending back out using fetch to the backend i'm getting:
RequestContentLengthMismatchError: Request body length does not match content-length header.
But I have made sure the content-length is the same size as the file. In this case it I set it to 1336842 which is the Byte size of the file (file1.size)

Comment: Added some images showing the content-length and size of the File before erroring with Fetch

Comment: What heppens when you only send one file?

Comment: Hey Matt i'm only just sending one image png file. Could it be I need to do extra encoding as the image File being sent to my remix app, has a different content length. I expect BOTH the image File sent to my remix app and the newly reconstructed File object to both have the same byte size

Comment: File byte size sent to remix app from the browser: 1337028. 
File byte size I reconstructed(file1) by code: 1336843

Comment: What size is your back end server saying it is?

Comment: It's not getting to the backend, it's failing on the fetch. I think the bytes of the new constructed file is bigger than the content length. I added an image of what that code looks like

Comment: It must get to the backend for the backend to tell you that it's failed. Have you checked the logs to see what the difference is?

Comment: Hey Matt, it does not reach to my BE after calling the fetch. It's failing in my local node_modules after calling fetch.(4 pic attached above)

Comment: Your code that is computing the `contentLength` using `reduce` looks weird, but I can't tell what the problem is unless you post the complete thing as [formatted text](/help/formatting) instead of a painting. Also why are you even trying to compute the content-length yourself instead of letting `fetch` do this (correctly) for you?

Comment: Ah, ok Bobby, my misunderstanding, sorry. What are the two values then? (i.e. `byteswritter + len` vs `contentLength`)

Comment: Hey Matt, the two value before RequestContentLengthMismatchError() gets called is 1310860 + 26123(len) > 1336843

Comment: Hello Bergi, I have added a image above(5th image) of when i do blob1.text(). It's spitting out all these weird diamond question marks(but on browser it's in a nice English readable text), Not sure if this is binary or something as not familiar with this area so much. I have to compute the content-length as I'm on a server side rendering app, when I call fetch with the endpoints(and other endpoints) I would need to calculate the content-length.

Comment: Please don't post images, post your code as text.

Comment: It's probably encoded and compressed, but we can't tell without seeing the rest of the code. And no, you should not need to calculate the `content-length` yourself, your server framework will do this for you if you let it.

Comment: @Bobby did you manage to find a solution ?? I'm stuck at this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Try passing the blob parts directly into the file constructor.

```
const myHandler: UploadHandler = async ({ name, contentType, data, filename }) =>
{
   const dataArray1 = [];

   for await (const x of data)
   {
      dataArray1.push(x);
   }

   const file1 = new File(dataArray1, filename, { type: contentType });

   return file1;
};
```